# Неверно вычитает время, на 3 часа больше

Tags: php

Хочу высчитать время светового дня. Все считает но ,на 3 часа больше

```
$Voshod =  $return_data->current_observation->astronomy->sunrise; //Время в формате АM PM
$Voshod =  date("G:i", strtotime($Voshod)); //Время в формате 24 часа
$Voshod_Un = strtotime($Voshod);//Время в формате Unix

$Zakat = $return_data->current_observation->astronomy->sunset;//Время в формате АM PM
$Zakat =   date("G:i", strtotime($Zakat ));//Время в формате 24 часа
$Zakat_Un = strtotime($Zakat);//Время в формате Unix

$Dlitelnost_dnya = $Zakat_Un - $Voshod_Un ; //Отнимаем время
$Dlitelnost_dnya =  date(' H:i ', $Dlitelnost_dnya); // Переводим в нормальный вид
```

На выходе имеем

> Восход солнца6:02 
>   Закат солнца19:33 
>   Длительность светового дня 16:31
>   А по идее должно быть 13:31, что не так ?

Comment: А кто вам разрешил считать длительность через date? Вы получили не промежуток а время 16:31 1 января 1970 года по Москве. Для промежутка вообще не нужна дата

Comment: Вы получили дату/время в московском часовом поясе (GMT+3).